# I've moved over to VSC from ST3, but there is no namespace auto finder/user to my knowledge, do you know of a plugin to achieve this?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've moved over to VSC (visual studio code) from ST3, my only problem is there is no namespace auto finder/use to my knowledge, do you know of a plugin to achieve this?

For example, if I done a method like so in sublime:

```
public function getJob(User $user)
{
    //nothing just a testmehthod 
}
```

and I pressed f5 over the `User` It'd import it, or if I pressed f6 it's include the full namespace... Any plugin for VSC like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code does have a 'quick fix'. In C# it will auto add using statements if they are missing for the statement under the cursor. The default keybinding is "ctrl+." according to the vscode documentation [keybindings page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings).

Not sure which language you're using so I cannot test it locally. I don't know which languages it works for or if other plugins are needed to work for more languages.